# SQL Server 2012 compatibility mode performance

Tags: sql-server-2012, backwards-compatibility, query-performance

I am investigating the impact of upgrading from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012. To reduce the immediate impact of migration, I am planning to set the database compatibility to SQL Server 2008.

Does anyone know if there is an impact on performance of queries and other DML operations compared to setting the database to SQL Server 2012?